# Catching exception during "with" keyword opening resource

Tags: python, postgresql, exception, psycopg2

For a concrete example, take `psycopg2` for Postgres(I'm aware `mysql.connection` has similar API):

```
try:
    with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
        ... # run a transaction with cursor, like insert
except IntegrityError as e:
    cursor.rollback()
```

will the cursor be able to rollback in this case or will the cursor resource be closed before rollback occurs in this case?

Comment: `cursor` will not be defined in your `except` statement, however the context manager itself should know what to do if it fails to initialize. If you're catching exceptions after initialization, nest them in the `with` block and `cursor` will be defined there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you swap `try:` and `with ...`?

```
with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    try:
        ... # run a transaction with cursor, like insert
    except IntegrityError as e:
        cursor.rollback()
```

In this way cursor will be in current scope when `except ...:` is reached.

<strike>With your code, when `except ...:` is reached, `cursor` will be `None`.</strike>

Comment: I like the answer, except... `cursor` will either be undefined (the exception happened during `connection.cursor()`) or a cursor object that has already been closed. It won't be `None`.

Comment: It depends on where `IntegrityError` can be raised and that's pretty far into the details of `connectino.cursor()` may do. Barring the code assigning `None` somewhere, it certainly won't be `None`.

Comment: I'm sorry I was looking at my code snippet. In OP's code certainly an exception raised from `connections.cursor()` is catched, and in that case `cursor` will be undefined at the `except:` block